# Объединить бинарные файлы

Tags: windows, node.js, файлы, bash, bat

В файле join.txt по одному на строке заданы имена файлов, которые надо объединить в порядке следования. Хочу это сделать в консоли.

Попытался сделать так (в командной строке, не в батнике):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %f in (join.txt) do type "%f" >>result.bin
```

но в одном из случаев где-то потерялся байт - суммарный размер не сходится на 1 байт и при сравнении с правильным файлом видно, что пропущен байт с кодом `1A`:

[image: скриншот]

Как объединить файлы так, чтобы бинарные данные не пострадали?

Comment: А `copy /b` вместо `type` в данном случае не подойдёт?

Comment: @MBo, не очень уверен, как 700 имён из файла упихать в команду copy через плюс. Насколько я помню, максимальная длина команды ограничена в Windows?

Comment: А почему это не сделать внутри виртуалки с линуксом?

Comment: @donRumata, кстати, в десятке же есть линуксовая подсистема - а что если через неё? Команду не подскажешь?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80182/discussion-on-question-by-qwertiy------javascript).

Answer (score 1):

Если используется Windows 10, в котором установлена линуксовая подсистема, то вместо командной строки можно использовать bash:

```
while read f || [[ -n $f ]]; do
  cat "$f" >>result.bin
done <join.txt
```

Работает и с линуксовыми, и с виндовыми переводами строк, независимо от наличия перевода строки в конце файла.

В ответе использованы:

- [Идея](//chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45654816#45654816) участника [@donRumata](//ru.stackoverflow.com/users/191416/don-rumata)
- [Построчное чтение файла](//stackoverflow.com/a/1521498/4928642)
  от [@BrunoDeFraine](//stackoverflow.com/users/6918/bruno-de-fraine)
- [Исправление для чтения последней строки](//stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash#comment31060693_1521498) от [mklement0](//stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)

Answer (score 0):

В общем, с командной строкой ничего не придумал и написал скрипт для node.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var filename = "join.txt"; // process.argv[2];
var dest = "result.bin"; // filename.replace(/\[names\](\.\w+)\.txt$/, "[full]$1");

if (filename === dest) {
  console.error("Can't determine dest filename");
  return;
}

var files = fs.readFileSync(filename, "utf8").split(/\r?\n/);
var resStream = fs.createWriteStream(dest, { flags: "wx" });

function go(i) {
  if (i === files.length) return resStream.end();

  var cur = fs.createReadStream(files[i])
  cur.pipe(resStream, {end:false});
  cur.on('end', () => go(i+1));
}

go(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Решается средствами batch. Нужно просто копировать всё в результирующий файл.
Создаем пустой файл, затирая старый. Затем все, найденное что в файл-списке,  помещаем в результат.

```
@copy /y nul result.bin
@for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (join.txt) do copy /b result.bin +"%%f" result.bin
```