# Слияние всех с++ файлов в один заголовок

Tags: c++, header

Как можно слить все `.cpp` файлы в один `.h` файл ?

Comment: В Windows - типа `type *.cpp > one.h` :)

Comment: @Harry множество файлов в один с помощью утилиты какой-то

Comment: А я что предложил?... Множество файлов в один. Утилита именуется `cmd.exe`.

Comment: (Стараясь не обращать внимание на бессмысленность затеи) В любой ОС есть десятки способов склеить несколько файлов в один. В чем проблема?

Comment: @Harry, не советую `type` - он [косячит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/854355/178988) :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Amalgamation - это альтернативный способ распространения исходного кода
>   библиотеки, используя только несколько файлов (всего один или два).
>   Этот инструмент производит объединение путем встраивания включенных
>   файлов для создания одного или нескольких больших исходных файлов или
>   файлов заголовков.

Например `sqlite` применяет этот способ для распостранения. Ссылки где можно посмотреть реализацию и утилиты:

- https://github.com/vinniefalco/Amalgamate
- https://github.com/edlund/amalgamate

Из практических советов в значительной степени все сводится к четырем правилам:

Устранить `using namepace` в верхней части исходных файлов. Вместо этого, как это более типично для заголовочных файлов, оберните весь код в `namespace` блоки и ограничьте `using namespace` внутренние функции. Очевидно, вы не хотите загрязнять глобальное пространство имен.

Оберните весь код, не предназначенный для непосредственного использования клиентом, во внутреннем вложенном пространстве имен, чтобы избежать загрязнения пространства имен вашей основной библиотеки. Я бы решил использовать `namespace Impl`, в то время как некоторые библиотеки, которые я видел, используют detail.

Добавьте предопределенный макрос перед всеми функциями, функциями-членами, конструкторами и деструкторами, определенными в исходных файлах. Это должен быть макрос-заполнитель, определяемый как ничего при обычной компиляции библиотеки, но его можно определить как `inline` в режиме с одним заголовком, или заменить на ключевое слово `inline` на этапе объединения.

Переместите все статические данные в исходных файлах (вне определений функций) в контейнерный класс или структуру как члены и объявите их `static inline`. Это новая функция `C++17`, которая устраняет необходимость написания кучки раздражающего стандартного кода, так что это абсолютная находка. Если вы этого не сделаете и просто добавите статические данные в заголовок, каждый модуль компиляции в конечном итоге будет иметь собственную копию статических данных. Это одинаково хорошо работает как с исходными, так и с заголовочными файлами, поэтому преобразование времени объединения не требуется.